# How to apply tensor symmetry and traceless properties to solve for an unknown quantity in terms of another variable?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

To specify, I have the following equation and I am trying to solve for $D_{\ell m}$ in terms of **K**:

$$K_{ijk}=\gamma_{ijk} + (\varepsilon_{ik\ell} \delta_{jm} + \varepsilon_{jk\ell}\delta_{im})D_{lm} + (\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}+\delta_{jk}\delta_{i\ell}-4\delta_{ij}\delta_{k\ell})v_{\ell}$$

Some important properties are:

1. $K_{ijk}$ is symmetric in the first two indices ($K_{ijk}=K_{jik}$)
2. $K_{ijk}$ is traceless in the last two indices ($K_{ikk} = 0$)
3. $\gamma_{ijk}$ is symmetric and traceless in all indices. I don't think its value is necessary in solving this problem but it is equal to $\frac{1}{3}(K_{ijk}+K_{kij}+K_{jki})-\frac{1}{15}(\delta_{ij}K_{ppk}+\delta_{ik}K_{ppj}+\delta_{jk}K_{ppi})$.
4. $v_\ell$ is equal to $-\frac{1}{10}K_{pp\ell}$

Specifically with $D_{lm}$, it is symmetric and traceless in both indices. I know the solution is$$D_{lm} = -\frac{1}{6}(K_{\ell pq}\varepsilon_{qpm}+K_{mpq}\varepsilon_{qp\ell})$$

but I am lost in the how. Any advice is appreciated in setting the problem up or which direction I need to go in. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $\varepsilon_{rkj}$, use the identities $\varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon^{imn}=\delta_j{}^{m}\delta_k{}^n - \delta_j{}^n\delta_k{}^m$ and $\varepsilon_{jmn} \varepsilon^{imn}=2{\delta_j}^i $. Note that the contraction of a skew symmetric- and symmetric tensor vanishes. Solve for $D_{ri}$. When $K_{puu}\equiv0$ you can use the relation $\varepsilon_{lmk}K_{ppk}=\varepsilon_{qpm}K_{lpq}-\varepsilon_{qpl}K_{mpq}$